# C# Bouncy Castle AES Decryption + GZ Decompression - varied length data fails

Tags: java, c#, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

With the following Code - I'm generally able to decrypt a token that I'm being passed.  The token string when decoded to json will look like the following:

```
\"id\":\"9efef759-15a3-4cd0-b1f1-fceab7ad0a6e\",
\"exp\":\"2016-07-23T15:27:50.758+12:00\", 
\"iv\":\"OOqNpy9puM5jPjTwrWHSNb+d5NYDEwIq2pZFqx6mraI14Kkh0bzEWADoU2d/KGu6cp9/FrVt4epheIP5Fw9qUFrdVcNYjLO5HWdJ0V5GhpdLJlFbMnFy4vS1rJ+4X1qTNZrqPwZh2deLceoHmxnqw7ml8JVFeIaz9H8BQXkgcNo=\",
\"ver\":\"1\",
\"iat\":\"2016-07-13T15:27:50.758+12:00\",
\"key\":\"d7R9blmqBYMywOEdYpRbd+gvKPfOqmxsRQMlDipkuGoWZobJ0dnK0MGBFAXq4wOdHbHVbfisjqm+6HoRSZ2w0KcfY+enPoKL5yptvlULkwpDtATEP8pnRmCh6ycWntbanL1gJI7RoNWTkomItBp/yODdL5kSMue76xAtIzc9+no=\",
\"sig\":\"X6A58tRDSUC5HJEP1VVmQjo17Qk2rJC9pYZiV5ccIjdcLmz7HPIkpm0ZCsFcQX4ps1k32asSojqOyegYFIdDqHypdrV9c5sHchIrp6Ak8MOjNTpy+SweTGPzkjlEHCMkWLVHjrkBq9mmoMk2o0sYyZes+/ARuYB8IjtAINtbAQE=\",
\"enc\":\"n+exbDhicBLuUtbYPXrrKESIktgyaidSreD5FWAxErGJeOyjTWv9QOqCGfEou5yJq2njCddf0mu0JOEP9i1mlhe1MUUa1hE4J+qnqxre+tSxWRNszHQL8Pk+0FV6cZ1nqk+aCfw9VOjlOLYXYmNF0NSZBqQIqzpobM3twHIf5u7pvJkvbnfP8Db0S83ZchNgMWyH1t+UEb+jbpcg1Um3U7Yb8Q==\"
```

The IV and key are pulled from the token and Asymmetrically decrypted then the enc text is symmetrically decrypted before they are passed to a gzip decompression.

```
internal virtual UserObj decrypt(string jsonToken, UserObj cls, System.Security.Cryptography.AsymmetricAlgorithm certPrivateKey)
{

   Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair bcPrivateKey;
   try
   {
        //Make a bouncyCastle private key for feeding to the rsa Engine.
        bcPrivateKey = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(certPrivateKey);
        // Attempt to unmarshal the JSON token
        Token token = encoder.unmarshalJsonString<Token>(jsonToken);

        // Asymmetrically encrypt the symmetric encryption iv
        Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines.RsaEngine rsaCipher = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines.RsaEngine();
        Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Encodings.Pkcs1Encoding rsaEncoder = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Encodings.Pkcs1Encoding(rsaCipher);

         rsaEncoder.Init(false, bcPrivateKey.Private);

         // Asymmetrically decrypt the symmetric encryption key
         byte[] encryptedAesKeyBytes = encoder.fromBase64String(token.Get(Token.ENCRYPTED_KEY));
         byte[] aesKeyBytes = rsaEncoder.ProcessBlock(encryptedAesKeyBytes, 0, encryptedAesKeyBytes.Length);

         // Asymmetrically decrypt the symmetric encryption IV
         byte[] encryptedAesIvBytes = encoder.fromBase64String(token.Get(Token.IV));
         byte[] aesIvBytes = rsaEncoder.ProcessBlock(encryptedAesIvBytes, 0, encryptedAesIvBytes.Length);

         //Setting equivalent excyption to "AES/CTR/NoPadding"
         Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines.AesEngine aes = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines.AesEngine();
         Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Modes.SicBlockCipher blockCipher = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Modes.SicBlockCipher(aes);
         Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher aesCipher = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(blockCipher, new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Paddings.ZeroBytePadding());

         Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.KeyParameter keyParam2 = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.KeyParameter(aesKeyBytes);

         // Symmetrically decrypt the data
         Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ParametersWithIV keyParamWithIv = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ParametersWithIV(keyParam2, aesIvBytes, 0, TokenEncryptor.IV_SIZE_BYTES);
         //
         // Symmetrically decrypt the data
         aesCipher.Init(false, keyParamWithIv);
         string encryptedData = token.Get(Token.ENCRYPTED_DATA);
         byte[] inputBytes = encoder.fromBase64String(encryptedData);
         byte[] compressedJsonBytes = new byte[aesCipher.GetOutputSize(inputBytes.Length)];
         //Do the decryption.  length is the proper size of the compressed data, compressedJsonBytes will
         //contain extra nulls at the end.
         int length = aesCipher.ProcessBytes(inputBytes, compressedJsonBytes, 0);

         //String to look at the compressed data (debug)
         string compressed = encoder.toBase64String(compressedJsonBytes);
         byte[] compressedJsonBytesProperSize = new byte[length];
         Array.Copy(compressedJsonBytes, compressedJsonBytesProperSize, length);

         //String to look at the compressed data (debug)
         compressed = encoder.toBase64String(compressedJsonBytesProperSize);
         byte[] jsonBytes = null;
         try
         {
               jsonBytes = encoder.decompress(compressedJsonBytesProperSize);
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
               jsonBytes = encoder.decompress(compressedJsonBytes);
         }
         string tmep = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(jsonBytes, 0, jsonBytes.Length);
         UserObj dataObj = encoder.fromJsonBytes<UserObj>(jsonBytes);

         return dataObj;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         throw new Exceptions.TokenDecryptionException(e);
    }
}
```

The final decrypted token looking something like this:

```
\"domain\":\"GLOBAL\",
\"user\":\"someuser\",
\"groups\":[\"GROUP1\",\"GROUP2\",\"GROUP3\"],
\"branchId\":\"0000\"
```

My problem occurs when depending on the number of items in the group, the GZ Decompression will fail.  On some tokens if I pass the full compressedJsonByte array (with nulls at the end), it complains about a CRC error (why I have the try/catch around the decompression), so then I pass it the trimmed byte array.  But for other tokens with more groups, it decompresses with the full byte array.

I have a comparable encryption routine and found that with everything else being equal if a alerted the user name from 17 to 19 characters I'd need to use the untrimmed byte array for decompression.  But have since found the problem runs deeper.

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm hoping its a decompression issue, but I suspect maybe something in the decrypting is fudging the end of the output byte array.

I'm not able to change the decryption type as it's coming from an external entity and their side is written in Java.

For reference the decompression routine is:

```
        public virtual byte[] decompress(byte[] compressedData)
        {
            try
            {
                //Push to a file for debug
                System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\temp\file.gz", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                fs.Write(compressedData,0,compressedData.Length);
                fs.Flush();
                fs.Close();

                byte[] outputBytes = new byte[4096];
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    using (System.IO.MemoryStream msInput = new System.IO.MemoryStream(compressedData))
                    {
                        System.IO.MemoryStream msOutput = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                        //using (System.IO.Compression.GZipStream gzs = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(msInput, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress))
                        using (ZLibNet.GZipStream gzs = new ZLibNet.GZipStream(msInput, ZLibNet.CompressionMode.Decompress))
                        {

                            int nRead;

                            bool canR = gzs.CanRead;
                            while ((nRead = gzs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                msOutput.Write(buffer, 0, nRead);

                            }
                        }
                        outputBytes = msOutput.ToArray();
                        if (outputBytes.Length == 0)
                            throw new Exception("Could not decompress");
                    }
                return outputBytes;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exceptions.ServiceException(e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `ZeroBytePadding` while CTR mode doesn't require any padding at all, you might as well directly use the `SicCipher` instance.

Zero byte padding will strip all the zero valued bytes from the end of the data, which is why you may end up with compromised data.

Zero byte padding is not deterministic and should not be used unless you're either:

- sure of the data not ending with a zero byte or bit;
- able to determine the plaintext length in other ways.

Comment: So I'd had a quick look at using the SicBlockCipher.  Does that mean that instead of aesCipher.ProcessBytes I'll need to enter into a loop with blockCipher.ProcessBlock for the length of inputBytes?

Comment: I also tried PaddedBufferedBlockCipher aesCipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(blockCipher);

And carried on, but exhibited the same problem where the compressed decrypted data is invalid.

Answer (score -1):

I may have just cracked it.  For the larger payload token, ProcessBytes would work in one pass.

For the smaller ones it took me a long while to notice that the length reported from ProcessBytes was less that the length of the inputBytes array.

I tried a DoFinal after the process bytes:

```
int length = aesCipher.ProcessBytes(inputBytes, compressedJsonBytes, 0);
int length2= aesCipher.DoFinal(compressedJsonBytes, length);
```

And for a token I encoded it worked...but for the given ones I have, it posted a Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.DataLengthException: last block incomplete in decryption

So finally I tried

```
int length2 = aesCipher.ProcessBytes(inputBytes,length,inputBytes.Length-length,compressedJsonBytes,length);
```

To process the remain data - and this worked.
So my resulting code now looks as follows - replacing the single line:

```
int length = aesCipher.ProcessBytes(inputBytes, compressedJsonBytes, 0);
```

With:

```
int length = 0;
while (length < inputBytes.Length)
{
    length += aesCipher.ProcessBytes(inputBytes, length, inputBytes.Length-length, compressedJsonBytes, length);
}
```

And this seems to have removed the need to take the full length compressed byte array.  The UncompressedProperSize byte array now down it's job properly.